# I'm getting compiler warnings with AFNetworking, but shouldn't be. How do I fix it?

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I'm using the most excellent `AFNetworking` library in a project that I'm currently upgrading to iOS 6. I'm in the middle of the upgrade, whittling down the bunch of warnings that I get when compiling against the iOS 6 SDK.

#### AFNetworking gives me two warnings in all targets:

```
SystemConfiguration framework not found in project, or not included in
precompiled header. Network reachability functionality will not be available.
```

and

```
MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in
precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files
in multipart requests will not be available.
```

Here's the thing, though: those two `libraries` **are** added in all my `targets`. I'd like to get rid of those warnings the proper way; I won't modify the `AFNetworking` files. I suspect it's Xcode being silly. It's admittedly a small thing, but leaving warnings around is bad practice.

How can I remove those warnings?

I've tried restarting Xcode and cleaning. Both don't work.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) or not but this is a known issue being tracked on the AFNetworking [Github page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/614).

I was able to fix this by adding the correct import statements directly to my `PROJECTNAME-Prefix.pch there I changed it to this.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#endif
```

If you have something else in there don't delete it. Just add the imports for SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreServices.

For OS X:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
    #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif
```

Comment: I'm not using CocoaPods, just a straight clone from github. I added MobileCoreServices and SystemConfiguration for other libraries, so didn't have to add them for AFNetworking.

Comment: Adding the import statements I posted to your .pch file in the Supporting Files group in your Xcode project should work. I just verified this fixing the warnings in a blank project.

Comment: Thank you for this. Sometimes when warning are still in Issue Navigator you have to remove derived data for current project in '~/Library/Xcode/Developer/DerivedData'. Then clean and build. Should works correctly.

Comment: I several 'PARSE ISSUES' and 'SEMANTIC ISSUES' if I add it there. However if I add it to the AFHTTPClient.h then those errors disappear.

Comment: Yes the only way I was able to get the warnings to disappear was to do what Pritesh Desai said and add the two frameworks to the top of AFHTTPClient.h

Comment: I am using CocoaPods, so this solution with the .pch won't work because the library has already been compiled.  Any other solutions?

Comment: @horseshoe7 this should work fine with CocoaPods you need to put this in your own `.pch` file and it will silence the warnings when linking from the generated static library

Comment: but the warning is in the pods project... oh wait, my bad.  it's in the AFIncrementalStore pod target... thanks!

Comment: @KeithSmiley I find it important to note that this has to be _before_ the import of `AFNetworking` itself.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using swift: Xcode compiles Swift code before the `Prefix.pch` file is compiled, so you'll get these warnings even if the correct imports are in your .pch file. The best solution I've found is to add them to the project's `Bridging-Header.h` file before importing AFNetworking:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

Comment: This worked for me. Key thing is to have the imports in both the PCH and the bridging header. Sequence is important so the imports must precede #import "AFNetworking.h"

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered, but still, if you're developing a command line tool potentially to be compiled for both OS X and iOS (not App Store for sure), you can add this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

    #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
        #import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
    #endif

#endif
```

By evaluating the target you're compiling to, it will include the proper files.