# Large amount of errors occurring when building my project that includes AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, afnetworking

Could anyone tell me what's going on? Bunch of errors occurred and I don't know why:

```
/JSONKit.m:680:12: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/JSONKit.m:931:17: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:

  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:

  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:

  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:

  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:

  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:

  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:

  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:

  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you used the -v to get more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the required frameworks. Import SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreservices/CoreServices for iOS or OS X respectively.

After that you may want to see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477109/im-getting-compiler-warnings-with-afnetworking-but-shouldnt-be-how-do-i-fix/13479569#13479569) to fix the compiler warnings.