# after updating xcode 6.4 to xcode 7 getting this issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, xcode7

I am getting this issue after updating xcode 6.4 to 7.0.

I am using `Objective C`

```
 ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking) for architecture arm64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to fix this ?

I tried to add `Prefix Header` but i was unable to get `LLVM 6.0`  there i am getting LLVM 7.0”

Comment: What is your project/dependency structure? Do you use Cocoapods?

Comment: It looks like that `AFNetworking.framework` is dynamic and you are targetting < iOS8.

Comment: yes i used AFNetworking

Comment: Check cersions you use in your build settings, something is incoherent here.

Comment: Run into same problem using dynamic framework with target deployment 7.0. Did't succeed to solve it.

Comment: no yet still in same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477109/im-getting-compiler-warnings-with-afnetworking-but-shouldnt-be-how-do-i-fix) that might have the solution. Keith Smiley suggested these import statements:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#endif
```